# Transform only certain entries in comma-separate file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a netlist file that contains some bitblasted signals. I want to change the signal name like below.

Its like

```
\abc[0],\abc[1].....
\xyz[0],\xyz[2]....
```

And I want it to be like

```
abc_0,abc_1....
xyz_1,xyz_1....
```

and I want this to be done only for particular set of signals, otherwise I would have just removed `\` and `]` and replaced `[` with `_`.

How to do it only for particular list of signals? Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you be more specific and describe _which_ "particular set of signale" are to be changed? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/582780/edit) your question to include example input and the corresponding desired output. Also, please show us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Using the data in the question:

```
$ sed 's/\\\([[:alnum:]]*\)\[\([[:digit:]]*\)\]/\1_\2/g' file
abc_0,abc_1.....
xyz_0,xyz_2....
```

The `sed` command matches the `\word[digits]` text, where `word` is any string of alphanumerical characters and where `digits` is a string of digits (these strings are allowed to be empty, change `*` to `\{1,\}` to require at least one character). The matching string is replaced by `word_digits`.  The substitution is made for all matches across all lines in the data.